# Sharepoint 2010 - Managed Client Object Model - How to access files within a document set (folder)

Tags: sharepoint, object, model, client

I have been searching all over the internet for this but no answers with specific reference to MANAGED CLIENT OBJECT MODEL.

How do i iterate over the files that are stored in a document set under a document library?
I have a list called SAMPLELIST and all document sets are stored within it. Each documentset can also house files. How do i iterate these files?

What I have found so far is LIST.ROOTFOLDER.FILES. However, this returns all files within the list (reference ROOFOLDER).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this

```
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sharepoint");
        List sharedDocumentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("SAMPLELIST");
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        string documentSetName = "DS1";
        camlQuery.ViewXml =
            @"<View>
            <Query>
              <Where>
                    <And>
                        <BeginsWith>
                            <FieldRef Name='ContentTypeId'/>
                            <Value Type='Text'>0x0120D5</Value>                                   
                        </BeginsWith>
                        <Eq>
                            <FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef'/>
                            <Value Type='Text'>" + documentSetName + @"</Value>
                        </Eq>
                    </And>
              </Where>
            </Query>
          </View>";
        ListItemCollection listItems = sharedDocumentsList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(sharedDocumentsList);
        clientContext.Load(listItems);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
        {
                clientContext.Load(item);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                Folder folder = clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(item.FieldValues["FileRef"].ToString());
                FileCollection files = folder.Files;

                clientContext.Load(folder);
                clientContext.Load(files);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (File file in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", file.Name);
                }
        }
```

Comment: can you also explain what the above does? And how to also retrieve other columns such as description within the same query?

Comment: @user1297985 the caml query search in document library for item with content type derive from DocumentSet (0x0120D5) and name equal to documentSetName. Document set have a folder that can be retrieved by clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl method. You can access other fields like this item.FieldValues[FieldName].

Answer (score 0):

### How to get files of Document Set via SharePoint CSOM

Assume the following structure:

```
/ (Root Site)
   |
   DocCenter (Site)
       |
     Documents (Library)
         |
       2013 (Document Set)
```

**Using Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl method**

Use [Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfolderbyserverrelativeurl(v=office.14).aspx) to get Document Set object located at the specified server-relative URL and then [Folder.Files property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.folder.files(v=office.14).aspx) to gets the collection of all files contained in the Document Set

```
var folderUrl = "/doccenter/Documents/2013";
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
    var files = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(folderUrl).Files;
    ctx.Load(files);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

**Query based approach**

The following example demonstrates how to return Files located in Document Set using [CAML query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery(v=office.14)):

```
var folderUrl = "/doccenter/Documents/2013";
var listTitle = "Documents";
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(webUri))
{
   var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
   var qry = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
   qry.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folderUrl;
   var items = list.GetItems(qry);
   ctx.Load(items, icol=> icol.Include(i => i.File));
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();

   //print file names            
   foreach (var item in items)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(item.File.Name);
   }
}
```

Key points:

- [CamlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.folderserverrelativeurl(v=office.14).aspx) is used to return
  only files located under specific url